# NavLink from ReactStrap has unexpected behavior - "to" and "activeClassName" not applying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, reactstrap

There is a larger wrapping component, called Sidenav:

```
const Sidenav = () => (
  <SidebarGroup>
    <SidebarLink to={routes.example1.path} name="example1" />
    <SidebarLink to={routes.example2.path} name="example2" />
  </SidebarGroup>
);
```

And the component that I'm mostly concerned about:

```
const SidebarLink = ({ to, name }) => (
  <li className={styles.sidebarlink}>
    <NavLink to={to} activeClassName={styles.active}>{name}</NavLink>
  </li>
);
```

I have 2 problems here.

1) Normally, `to` works perfectly to redirect to the destination URL. However, when I switched to using `NavLink` from ReactStrap vs. `Link`, `to` no longer works - `href` has to be used instead in order to correctly perform the click-through action. Other examples online of people using `NavLink` are all using `to` - is there some kind of dependency I'm  missing?

2) I want to apply `activeClassName` to the menu item that is currently tabbed to or is being clicked on. Hypothetically, again, the syntax is correct but it is not working as anticipated - specifically, the `.active` class is not being applied when you click on or tab through the menu item in question. Again, is this a dependency error, or something else? `withRouter` was suggested in one place, but that did not make a difference.

Thank you in advance for any guidance!

Comment: Is your `Sidenav` component a child/descendent of the `BrowserRouter`, so that the same `history` will be used throughout the entire app?

Comment: Yes - `BrowserRouter` surrounds the entire application in `App.jsx`, which calls the main layout, which calls the `Sidenav`.